# Maven Build Error Failure authenticating with NTLM

Tags: maven

When i am trying to build a maven package using `mvn package` command, it tries to download the dependencies. while downloading this dependenices i get the error NLTM authentication faliure. I have also updated the maven setting files for proxy setting.
Error:

```
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-  resources-plugin/2.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.3.pom
May 24, 2013 10:10:01 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor   selectAuthScheme
INFO: ntlm authentication scheme selected
May 24, 2013 10:10:01 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector authenticate
SEVERE: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication: org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials
```

Comment: Have you checked this page?  http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Configuring+Maven+behind+an+NTLM+proxy  The suggestion is to install a secondary proxy for a proxy-to-proxy connection.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539048/maven-behind-a-auto-generated-proxy